# Cache Busting - Query String vs URL Path

Tags: http, caching, proxy, browser-cache

So to be sure a stale asset isn't served up, people often use something like:

```
example.com/css/styles.css?v=1
```

or

```
example.com/css/styles-v1.css
```

Similar tactics are used by libraries like jQuery to request JSONP resources (using the query-string approach). Likewise, analytics services use tracking pixels with cache-busting in the URL.

My question is, does anyone have any real data on what percentage of caching proxies (or other mechanisms) might ignore the query-string, making the URL-path option preferable?

I've heard of mobile internet providers and corporate environments having severe caching rules but I haven't seen any real data.

Comment: No. I couldn't find any information to indicate that one is better than the other.

Comment: This answer explains [why the path solution is better](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34626594/33236).

Comment: Thanks @hultqvist!

Answer (score 0):

No data, but any proxy stripping the query string would per definition be non-compliant. Having done a ton of work with this stuff, I would definitely say:

1. A bug might exist in some implementation.
2. It's probably uncommon enough for you not to care.